# Google Analytics API - No Source Info on Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics

My goal is to setup some campaigns using the analytics.js library.  Everything is working fine except when I go to Traffic Sources / Sources and look at All Traffic, or drill down into the campaigns, I'm seeing the url I'm tracking not the source of the hit (referrer) as I hope.  Here is my code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','__gapmi');
var ref = document.referrer;
var url = document.URL;
__gapmi('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1',{'alwaysSendReferrer': true});
__gapmi('set', 'campaignName', 'campaign');
__gapmi('set', 'campaignId', 'campaign');
__gapmi('set', 'referrer', ref);
__gapmi('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 3):

_setCampSourceKey() is used for the purpose .. 
setCampSourceKey(newCampSrcKey) sets the campaign source key, which is used to retrieve the campaign source from the URL. "Source" appears as a segment option in the Campaigns report.

For example, suppose you have an ad on another website with this URL to your site: 
http://mysite.net/index.htmlsource=giganoshopper.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Christmas+specials&utm_content=Garden+gloves 
in this URL, the key "source" delineates the source in the URL for that campaign.

Async Snippet (recommended)
_gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', 'source']);

traditional (ga.js) Snippet
parameters
String   newCampSrcKey **Campaign source key to set**

Comment: Ah, I think you've almost got me there except I am using analytics.js.  Note that I changed the function call from ga to __gapmi perhaps causing a bit of confusion.  would: __gapmi('set', 'campaignMedium', 'referrer');   be appropriate then?